# Golang 1.21 not exporting functions when using import "C"

Tags: go, cgo

Recently I am trying to upgrade my Go microservice from 1.15 to 1.21.

The code used to work, but now in one of my packages I get this warning:
`This file is within module "services\\my-service", which is not included in your workspace. To fix this problem, you can add a go.work file that uses this directory.`

And I can't see the functions from other packages. However if I remove the `import "C"` line from the code, the warning goes away and the functions are successfully exported, but of course I can't call C functions from my Go code.

Does anyone know what happened and how I can fix it?
Thank you.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
/services
 - (other, independent micro-services, not written in Go)
 - /my-service
   - Dockerfile
   - go.mod
   - go.sum
   - main.go
   - /routes
     - model.go
     - router.go
   - /sdk
     - /include --> .h files
     - /libs --> .so files
     - types.go
     - invoice.go
```

Having something like this in the `types.go` file:

```
package sdk

import (
    "sync"
)

type client struct {
    ... // simple structs
}
```

and `invoice.go`:

```
package sdk

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I${SRCDIR}/sdk/include
#cgo linux,386 LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/libs -ldinvoicesdk
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "include/invoices.h"
*/

import "C"
import (
    "errors"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "unsafe"
)

const (
    invalidToken int = 0
    timeoutMs    int = 1000
)

func Initialize() {
    C.Invoice_Initialize(0)
    log.Printf("Initialize - invoice native client initialized\n")
}
```

I can't see the `Initialize` function from outside the module, it says that it is undefined. If I remove the `import "C"` statement, it can find it but of course I cannot call native C code. This worked perfectly in version 1.15 (although I didn't use `go.mod` files).

These are the `go.mod` and `go.sum` files:

```
module inv

go 1.21.6

require github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.1
```

```
github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.1 h1:TuBL49tXwgrFYWhqrNgrUNEY92u81SPhu7sTdzQEiWY=
github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.1/go.mod h1:AKf9I4AEqPTmMytcMc0KkNouC66V3BtZ4qD5fmWSiMQ=
```

And this would be the `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "inv/routes"
    "inv/sdk"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)
    sdk.Initialize() --> this is undefined

    router := routes.NewRouter()
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", router)
}
```

Comment: Care to produce [an MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean)? Presently the chances of your question being answered are only as high as your post ending up being read by someone who has had the exactly same problem.

Comment: I can't provide the C header files and shared libraries because they are a third party's closed sources.  I will edit my post with some more info and code though.

Comment: I am a little confused. The error is complaining about a "services/my-service", yet your folder structure makes no mention of a services directory. I don't think what you are showing is the whole truth. That go.work file is part of workspaces which were added in go 1.18. Go seems to be under the impression that you have a multi module setup here which would explain why it is recommending you to setup a workspace.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, my whole structure I showed is below another folder called `services`, but the rest of the code is not in Go and the other services have no Go related code, modules, or anything like that.

Comment: Since there are no other suggestions (probably using native C code in Go is not really that common), the only thing I can offer is that it is very brave to upgrade so many versions at once. Maybe you should do it more controlled by going up one version at a time and seeing what breaks. Then when something breaks you can see what changed in that version of Go that might cause it. Maybe some semantics have changed in how Go resolves native functions.

Comment: Gonna try that and see what happens, thank you!